# How this flying copter actually work

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

The link below shows a drone copter without any swash plate mechanism only using two bldc motors which accelerate and deccelerate per cycle creating lateral force and moment. How does it work? I want to know how its control mechanism works. Plz watch the video, link is below. Any suggestion will be helpful [video link](https://youtu.be/qWsKqmCIhRY)

Comment: 1/ Edit your question to make it not one big link. 2/ I don't see what swash plates have to do with electronics. 3/ I want to know how ... works. is not a specific question. We are not an educational service website, certainly not about aeronautics  questions on an EE website.

Comment: @Oldfart maybe "how it works" is not an electronic question, but the control of that copter is impossible without some very advanced electronics. I got an itch to make one just by watching ten seconds of that video :)

Comment: Not strictly on topic, but that was a very interesting video.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... clever!

The secret is in "lag-pitch" hinge (see at 1:06). The axis of it is angled in a way that makes the blade to change pitch when it falls behind (hence "lag-pitch") the radial position. Faster rotation generates more drag on the blades, more drag - more lag and therefore bigger pitch change.

So, for example, if you suddenly accelerate the rotor hub then blades fall behind it. This makes one blade to increase pitch, the other to decrease it. The end result is the same as in standard cyclic control - the rotor tilts on the teetering hinge and creates sideways thrust.

By timing these increases and decreases of speed at different points of a turn you can create thrust in any direction.

Comment: If I add a sinusoidal speed reference signal (which already sychronized with motor shaft angle ) to constant speed reference signal fed to bldc drone motor through a PID control, will motor generate oscillating torque /acceleration or track the combine speed reference signal.Did he applied the same principle or any thing else

Comment: In theory it should work. A lot depends on the mechanical responsiveness of the system. For example I think bigger rotor at less RPM would work better for this.

Comment: If you could use the same trick with a non-coaxial twin (Chinook) you might well have a winner.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't see why not. Half-O-Copter :)

Comment: It seems to me a design that looks like a conventional helicopter would also work well (one big main motor/rotor, and a much smaller tail motor and variable pitch prop to counteract the main rotor torque) and be cheaper and easier to implement for a full size (man-carrying) helicopter.

Comment: @VincePatron Yeah, but why would one add boring old tail rotor to such fun modern design :)